# how to unbind M-1 in spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I used spacemacs for my work, now I need to unbind M-1 with following, but not work

(global-unset-key (kbd "M-1"))
I checked binding, it looks M-1 was used by winum-select-window-1.anyone knows how to unbind this key bind?  thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keybinding is defined in the `winum-keymap`. You can unbind it using:

```lisp
(define-key winum-keymap (kbd "M-1") nil)
```

`global-unset-key` is for removing global keybindings only, not bindings defined in specific keymaps. You can try using it after you have removed the definition from the winum-keymap (to remove its binding as a digit argument). However, there is no need to remove it, if you want, then you can just redefine it directly using `global-set-key`.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works